# Call a validation method in application service

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

How can to call a method from a validator class in application service Whenever needed and throw exception messages and show its in 'aspnetboilerplate' based project?

Comment: Sorry it's hard for me you catch your requirement, could you pls describe it more vividly?

Comment: there's a dto that passed to a method as a parameter and i used ABP.FluentValidation for checking validations, ABP will run Validator class to validate dto class automatically.... now, i want to call methods that is in Validator class from application service Whenever needed

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractValidator<T>` has `Validate` method. [see](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/main/src/FluentValidation/AbstractValidator.cs#L61).

```
Install-Package Abp.FluentValidation
```

```
public class MyDto
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<MyDto>
{
    public MyDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Value).InclusiveBetween(1, 99)
            .WithMessage("Value must be between 1 and 99");
    }
}
```

```
var myDtoInstance = new MyDto{ Value: 505 };
var myValidatorInstance = new MyValidator();
myDtoValidatorInstance.Validate(myDtoInstance);
```

Exception is thrown on the last line with your custom message.

Also see `AbstractValidator` [tests](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/main/src/FluentValidation.Tests/AbstractValidatorTester.cs#L105).

Comment: it can help me, thanks for your Cooperation ;)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to call a method from a validator to validate a DTO.

See under the **FluentValidation** caption in this [link](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Validating-Data-Transfer-Objects)

```
Install-Package Abp.FluentValidation
```

```
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpFluentValidationModule))]
public class MyProjectAppModule : AbpModule
{
    
}
```

```
public class MyDto
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyTestController : AbpController {

    public JsonResult GetJsonValue([FromQuery] MyDto dto)
    {
        return Json(new MyDto
        {
            Value = dto.Value
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class MyDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<MyDto>
{
    public MyDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Value).InclusiveBetween(1, 99);
    }
}
```

Comment: MyDtoValidator class and its methods call automatically and this is not what I want, i want to call methods of MyDtoValidator class Whenever needed